# Converting date string with Months name in excel to date

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel that has a string column with dates like "`Oct 4, 2023 8:55am`"

How can I convert this value to a date column of type date.

I am trying to use `=DATEVALUE(TEXT(CELL_VALUE, "MMM D, YYYY) + TIMEVALUE(CELL_VALUE, "H:M AM/PM"`

Is this the right forumula to use?

Comment: Clearly this `=DATEVALUE(TEXT(CELL_VALUE, "MMM D, YYYY) + TIMEVALUE(CELL_VALUE, "H:M AM/PM"` formula won't work it is incomplete and wrong as well, what is your excel version?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider using Power Query to do this:

Export data to Power Query:

[image: Export data to Power Query]

Power Query will automatically convert the string to a date value. Just hit the 'Close & Load' button and you're finished. This makes it really easy.

Hit "Close & Load" button:

[image: Hit 'Close & Load' button]

Answer (score 0):

*Assuming no **`Excel Constraints`** as per the tags posted then could use one of the following :*

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1," ",3)+TRIM(REPLACE(RIGHT(A1,7),6,0," "))
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>C1</kbd>

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,RIGHT(A1,7),)+TRIM(REPLACE(RIGHT(A1,7),6,0," "))
```

---

Or, with single dynamic array formula:

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=REDUCE(A1,{"am","pm"},LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUTE(x,y," "&y)))+0
```

---

The above solutions returns both the date & time, if you need only dates then,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=TEXTBEFORE(A1," ",3)+0
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell C1

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1,RIGHT(A1,7),)+0
```

---

Or,

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=INT(REDUCE(A1,{"am","pm"},LAMBDA(x,y,SUBSTITUTE(x,y," "&y)))+0)
```

---

Simple and sleek approach suggested by Sir **[P.b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12634230/p-b)**

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B1</kbd>

```
=--TRIM(REPLACE(A1:A2,LEN(A1:A2)-1,0," "))
```

---

One more way if one faces any issues with system language, then may use the following which works with <kbd>DUTCH VERSION</kbd> of Excel as suggested by P.b. Sir.

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>B4</kbd>

```
=LET(
     a,A4:A5,
     m,TEXTBEFORE(a," "),
     v,TRIM(REPLACE(a,LEN(a)-1,0," ")),
     IFERROR(--v,--SUBSTITUTE(v,m,XLOOKUP(m,G1:G12,H1:H12))))
```

---

Excel for download : **[here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckAb3tiuGSS3caauB?e=VJl3uz)**

---

Comment: I think the question was how to convert a string/text to date format.

Comment: @tnavidi yeah, i agree, shown both additionally. Updated that as well thanks buddy =)

Comment: I'm getting `#VALUE` on both your answers; specifically when evaluating formula it comes down to "Oct 4, 2023" + "8:55 am" ->The next evaluation will result in error

Comment: @tnavidi What is your Excel Version? Here is an **[Excel File](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AlEkksoPTc2ckAb3tiuGSS3caauB?e=Ip2wcT)** download to check for your reference

Comment: Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2307 Build 16.0.16626.20198) 64-bit

Comment: Yes download the file, it will certainly work. btw I'm using : `Microsoft® Excel® for Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2311 Build 16.0.16926.20000) 64-bit `

Comment: @tnavidi It may be caused by the language. If your system language isn't the same as the month names in the string it will result in an error.
@MayukhBhattacharya very nice solutions! This could also work for both year and time: `=--TRIM(REPLACE(A1:A2,LEN(A1:A2)-1,0," "))`

Comment: @P.b Sir, wow thats a nice addition, let me post it. May help someone in the future

Comment: Ok, I tried your excel file, it's definitely a language issue as suggested by P.b. Thanks for the extra effort

Comment: @tnavidi no worries, thanks for your thoughts and insights !

Comment: I think it may be a system language versus string langue issue. 
This may work: 
`=LET(a,A1:A2,m,TEXTBEFORE(a," "),v,TRIM(REPLACE(a,LEN(a)-1,0," ")),IFERROR(--v,--SUBSTITUTE(v,m,XLOOKUP(m,D1:D12,E1:E12))))`
here `D1:D12` hold strings of the month names in English. and E1:E12 hold the strings  of the month names in your system language. https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVEnU.png

Comment: @P.b Sir, I am adding this as well, so the answer captures the solutions pertaining to the system language.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative which recognises that there will probably also be times after mid-day:
[image]

Formula in B1

```
=VALUE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A1,5,3)&" "&REPLACE(A1,5,3,),",",""),LEN(A1)-2))+(MID(A1,SEARCH("?m",A1),1)="p")*0.5
```